Manually adding citations to ResearchGate
The source information of scientific publications uploaded to ResearchGate is often not recognized automatically. As a result, the cited works cannot be recorded in the statistics.
Can I add source information to my uploaded publication  so that ResearchGate can record it and include it in the statistics?

As has been discussed several times in various forums, there is no direct way to add source information manually. However, there are proven workarounds. Based on this idea, the following procedure has proven to be effective.

The following steps only work BEFORE the paper has been uploaded to
ResearchGate. (If it has already been uploaded, the entry must
first be deleted)

Copy all the sources of your paper into a new
Word document: do not use any special formatting, font size 6,
landscape, Arial. IEEE often works as a citation style. Name the
document “References”, or something similar.

Create a new ResearchGate entry (e.g. "Conference Paper") for your publication and upload the previously created PDF "References"
as a private copy to the newly created entry. (ResearchGate should now have recognized all the references automatically)

Add your actual publication as a public full text
to the created entry.


